# Getting fontspec Fonts with pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, fontspec, font-encodings

I have to make a document, which was originally written in LuaLaTeX, compatible for both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Everything works except that the fonts differ. How can I force pdfLaTeX/fontenc to use the same fonts as fontspec?

Minimal example (omitted ifluatex to avoid clutter):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
% \usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    Text with some formulas: $a=1$.
\end{document}
```

By using `lmodern`, the fonts of the text seem to almost coincide, but the math fonts differ:

```
# pdffonts output for pdflatex with lmodern, fontenc and inputenc:
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZGMFNK+LMSans10-Bold                 Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
YIMXCY+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
GXEVRM+LMMathItalic10-Regular        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
YIMXCY+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       7  0

# pdffonts output for lualatex with fontspec:
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SSPBGH+LMSans10-Bold                 CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
XXBUAG+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
EDWHGC+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
HVZLMP+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
```

So, the type and encoding differs, and the math fonts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to get the same font encodings for LuaTeX and pdfTeX, for the simple reason that LuaTeX with `fontspec` uses OpenType fonts, whereas pdfTeX uses Type 1 fonts.  It is possible to get the same math fonts, though, by passing the option `nomath` to `lmodern`.

If you are using the 2018 version of LaTeX, you can remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` because [UTF-8 is now the standard encoding](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2018/04/10/issue28-of-latex2e-news-released/).

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\ifdefined\directlua
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    Text with some formulas: $a=1$.
\end{document}
```

Run through `pdflatex` I get this

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
$ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZGMFNK+LMSans10-Bold                 Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
KOIJYY+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
EDWHGC+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
HVZLMP+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
```

Run through `lualatex` I get this

```
$ lualatex test.tex
$ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SSPBGH+LMSans10-Bold                 CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
HXVMKT+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
EDWHGC+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
HVZLMP+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
```